# How chain rule and partial derivative are applied on gradient descent in deep learning?

Tags: neural-networks

Suppose there is a DNN like this:

$h = t(w_1x+b_1)$
$g = t(w_2h+b_2)$
$\hat y = t(w_3g+b_3)$
$Loss = \frac 12\sum (y - \hat y)^2$

Just one input $x$
$t$ is activation function.

**Could you explain with equations how the gradients of $w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$ is calculated?**

By the way, when combining partial derivative and chain rule,

$\frac {dk}{dg}\frac {dg}{dh}\frac {dh}{dx}$ -> $\frac {\partial k}{\partial g}\frac {\partial g}{\partial h}\frac {\partial h}{\partial w_1}$

is the above fine?

Comment: how is y related to h,g and k?

Comment: I edited my question. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just execute the chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_1}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \hat y}\frac{\partial \hat y}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial h}\frac{\partial h}{\partial w_1}$$

Then, we calculate each term separately, e.g.
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial w_1}=t'(w_1x+b_1)x,\frac{\partial g}{\partial h}=t'(w_2h+b_2)w_2,\cdots$$

Your chain rule is not fine, because we don't ever calculate $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$ since $x$ is not a parameter nor an outcome.

Comment: What about calculating w_2? Is it just to substitue w_1 into w_2 and calculate the equation which you wrote?

Comment: it’s similar, but upto the term h, not g because it’s not in the first layer.

Comment: so $\frac {\partial L}{\partial w_2} = \frac {\partial L}{\partial \hat y}\frac {\partial \hat y}{\partial g}\frac {\partial g}{\partial w_2}$ is right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right